# Human body and current flow effects

Tags: safety

This is kind of theoretical question, but I hope that it will not bother anyone and it will not be reported or closed after a minute.

In all basic electrical literature there is always information about most important and dangerous things like neurological current flow effect, but there is not much details about other effects, only an information that other effects happen too.

I saw here few guys related with bioengineering and medical equipment, maybe they can share some advanced knowledge about this.

I want to ask **what are current flow effects** other than:

- neurological effects that may stop heart
- skin damage from heat

What else may happen? What is going on in body cell scale? Are there some cells vulnerable more than other? For example - blood cells contain iron - can some electrolysis happen there? Or in some other cells?

Comment: When someone's heart stops beating, you focus your attention on that and not so much on whether some other less-critical body function has changed slightly.

Comment: Current in an electrolyte, including the various tissues of the body, is carried by ions rather than bare electrons. Prolonged direct current causes those ions to migrate to/from the electrodes. This causes localized chemical irritation. Most direct applications of electricity for medical uses (TENS, electrosurgery) tend to use AC.

Comment: @Theran Not necessarily AC, but many physiological stimulators are certainly charge balanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The effects of electric shock are many, and most of them seem to do with neuropathy, that is, damage to the nervous system, including the brain. From the Wiki article on electric shock:

> Many people survive electrical trauma only to find a host of injuries
>   including loss of consciousness, seizures, aphasia, visual
>   disturbances, headaches, tinnitus, paresis, and memory disturbances.
>   Even without visible burns, electric shock survivors may be faced with
>   long-term muscular pain and discomfort, fatigue, headache, problems
>   with peripheral nerve conduction and sensation, inadequate balance and
>   coordination, among other symptoms. Electrical injury can lead to
>   problems with neurocognitive function, affecting speed of mental
>   processing, attention, concentration, and memory. The high frequency
>   of psychological problems is well established and may be
>   multifactorial. As with any traumatic and life-threatening experience,
>   electrical injury may result in post traumatic psychiatric disorders.

The mechanisms are unclear. Why, for instance, does ECT (Electroconvulsive Therapy) seem to work?

Electrolysis does not seem to be a factor.

Answer (score 3):

Going from low currents to higher:  After just a tingley feeling, the next step would be muscle contraction which can actually prevent a victim from letting go oof the thing shocking them.  Next might come respiratory and cardiac arrest.  Then burns.

On the cellular level, currents cause electrical charges to cross cell membranes, changing membrane voltages.  For excitable membranes inherent to nerve and muscle, ionic channels in cell membranes open and close in response to changed membrane voltages, and these cause even more changes in voltage.  The physiological processes involved in neural conduction and muscle contraction are often positive feedback mechanisms, and when extraneous electric currents inappropriately start these positive feedback systems bad things happen.